# android setError method interfering with manually setting icons

Tags: android

I'm using the `setError` method to show if an `EditText` field is incorrectly filled when the focus from that field shifts away. If it's correctly filled, I'm showing an icon: `drawable.validated` Here's my code:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    zip.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                if (isValidZip(zip.getText().toString())) {
                    zip.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.validated, 0);
                } else {
                    zip.setError(getString(R.string.zip_error));
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem is, the `setError` method is interfering with my manually setup of icon. And thus I can't see the `drawable.validated` icon even when the field is verified.

**MORE DETAILS on when I get the error:**

**CASE 1** I fill the EditText field correctly in the very first time -> I change the focus from that field -> I can see the `validated` icon. See the following screenshot:

[image]

**CASE 2** I fill the `EditText` zip field **incorrectly** -> I change the focus to Mobile Number field-> I see error in zip field-> Get back to the zip field and fill it correctly. Error in zip disappears -> change focus to Mobile Number field-> Now I can't see the `VALIDATED` icon in the zip field even if it is correctly filled:

[image: no-validation symbol shown]

`drawable.validated` is the blue-tick.

`12345` is the `zip` field

What might be the issue and how to resolve that?

Comment: Could you provide screenshots it would be much easier to understand the problem.

Comment: sure. I'll upload in a minute.

Comment: @CROSP, I've updated the question with images. Please check.

Comment: Let me check, I will post results

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you `setOnFocusChangeListener` every time text change, you don't need to do this, you can just set it once.

I have just created test project and test it, works fine

```
mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_input);
mEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                if (isValidZip(mEditText.getText().toString())) {
                    mEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_validated, 0);
                } else {
                    mEditText.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_zip));
                }
            }
        }
    });
 private boolean isValidZip(String s) {
        return s.equals("correct");
    }
```

Works as it should.I think your problem is that you are setting change listener every time text change.

You can try my application to see if it works correctly https://dropmefiles.com/a9ydI

Here the link to the complete source code

https://bitbucket.org/CROSP/testedittexterror/commits/all

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But I think the error is still produced. Steps to reproduce the error: 1. Restart the app. 2. Write `corr` in the first box. 3. Now, tap on the second EditText to change focus from the first box. 4. Next, get back to the first box and write the remaining `ect`. 5. Tap on the second box again to change focus to the second box. 6. no tick symbol is shown.

Comment: It is weird,I have just followed your steps and everything works fine. Maybe you do something else with `EditText`, I have updated my answer with the full code link.

Comment: I've uploaded the results I'm getting here. 5 screenshots in total. Please check. http://dropshots.com/akeshwarjha/date/2016-02-02/01:55:03

Comment: also, i had to restart and follow those steps to produce the error. could it have something to do with the api version?

Comment: I don't think that it is the problem with API. Here I uploaded the video https://dropmefiles.com/ORHV5 . Maybe I don't understand correctly what is the problem

Comment: Or you need to have icon visible after each symbol is typed in edit text ?

Comment: astonishing. I'm doing the exact same thing. I will also check on an emulator and update you the results.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter if the icon is visible or not after each keystroke. But I need the symbols as soon as the focus changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102324/discussion-between-crosp-and-akeshwar).